# Random images on page refresh using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to randomise images on page reload and store them in localStorage so the previous one does not load on the next refresh but i'm having problems just displaying the images at all. here is my html:

```
<ul class="grid">
    <li class="small overlay" id="random-image" onclick="location.href='switchblade.html'">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">The pivot switchblade</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the jQuery for it:

```
$(function () {
    var url = "../img/switchblade/",
    imageArray = [
        url+"pivot-switchblade.jpg",
        url+"switchblade-01.jpg",
        url+"switchblade-08.jpg",
        url+"switchblade-05.jpg",
        url+"switchblade-06.jpg",
    ],
    randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * imageArray.length)),
    baseUrl = "url('" + imageArray[randomNumber] + "')";

    $("#random-image").css('background-image', baseUrl);
})();
```

The url is 100% correct so i know that's not the problem.

Any help would be very much appreciated and also any help with the localStorage would be also be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any errors, either js or network, from DevTools?

Comment: The only error i'm getting is: Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function

Comment: remove last (), not right syntax.

Comment: I have just noticed that you cant use ../ to back up a directory and if i put assets/img/switchblade/ that is works. Funny thing is i'm sure i had already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine, since its a background image, height and width needs to be given to display the image.
Also you have to remove "()" from the last, because it wass throwing some error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(...)` undefined means there is no jQuery loaded, load jQuery and if it is loaded then convert `$(...)` to `jQuery(...)` because some frameworks like Wordpress don't accept `$`. And `()` at end don't make any sense. Otherwise code is working fine.